# Trigger an click event on the DOM published by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery code that makes a div `onClick` with certain class `.caption`. After when I triggered click event in `.caption` this class then it doesnot work. How can I do this.

```
  $('#edit').on('click',function(){
      var pre = '<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" style="margin:0 auto;"><div class="thumbnail"><div class="caption" style="text-align:center;">';     
      $("#imgs").append(pre);

 });

  $('div.thumbnail').on('click','.caption',function(){
     alert("Del");
});
```

Comment: `div.thumbnail` has to exist when code runs, try using `#imgs` as first selector

Comment: I don't know why this question get down voted.Any reason.

Comment: Thanks it really did the trick and worked like charm. @charlietfl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because as what @charlieftl has pointed out in the comments, the element `div.thumbnail` does not exists at runtime, and it is not possible to bind a click event to an element that is not present...

What you can do, however, is to rely on event bubbling — for example, when the click event is triggered on a newly added `.caption`, it actually *bubbles* up all the way to the top of the DOM tree (to the `document` object). You can listen to this bubbling on any element that is already present at runtime — of course it is safest to listen on `document` since it is an object that is *always* present:

```
$(document).on('click', '.caption', function(){
    alert("Del");
});
```